# How to get the taggable_friends user profile id's using Cordova-plugin-facebook4?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

[PICTURE! Id's are like these. and they got changed everytime i hit Submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmY4I.png)I am using Facebook Graph API to login with facebook in my ionic App project.
I successfully login in using their javascript sdk and sample code.
The problem occurs at the point when i try to fetch my taggable friends. All friends are coming back as response but the id's of friends are a long string and gets change on every request. What is that id? Because the facebook profile id for each user is short and sweet which only contains numbers. But this id is type of encrypted key. Can anybody help me solving this mystery? How can i get the correctly formatted user profile id from facebook javscript sdk.
PS i am using Cordova-plugin-facebook4 plugin for this. Because i am working in ionic.

Comment: _“How can i get the correctly formatted user profile id from facebook javscript sdk”_ - not at all, because you are not supposed to. This endpoint exists for one single purpose - tagging friends in Open Graph stories. You are not supposed to use it for anything else, and it is explicitly not a “workaround” to circumvent the limits Facebook has placed on access to a user’s friends.

Answer (score 1):

It is a tagging token, and you can only use it for tagging. There is no way to get IDs of users who did not authorize your app.